# EMR Spark - How can I see the progress of writing files to S3?

Tags: apache-spark, emr, amazon-emr

Is there any service in EMR or way where I can see a progress bar(or elapsed time) when I submit a job of creating parquet files to S3?

The code:

```
df.write.partitionBy("date").mode("append").parquet("s3n://uk-adp-vault/semasio/output")
```

Comment: From my experience, you should avoid appending new data this way. The runtime is ~linear with the amount of the existing data on s3. see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40830152/how-to-avoid-reading-old-files-from-s3-when-appending-new-data

When using s3-dist-cp I can see the progress in the resource manager (http://<master_ec2_ip>:8088/cluster)

Comment: What Niros is suggesting is correct, nevertheless the job progress is in the Spark UI

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the ResourceManager using the 8088 port on EMR. This will show you the memory utilization.

From there you can navigate to ApplicationMaster which is the spark UI for the cluster. That will show you the progress of that job with details of each task.